# SetProperties SP not accepting image data type

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, stored-procedures

Trying to use asp.net stored procedure dbo.aspnet_Profile_SetProperties to create a record in aspnet_Profile.

If I create a query in server Management studio:

```
DECLARE @todayDate datetime
SET @todayDate = Getdate()

EXEC aspnet_Profile_SetProperties 'geoappbuilder' , 'ChangePassword111', 'true', '', 'ydwxytog@tryalert.com', 0, @todayDate
```

this adds a record to the aspnet_profile table.

However I want to create a record from my project in Visual studio. flagging an error when I try to pass in `@PropertyValuesBinary   image,` in the query I can use an empty string '', but this does not work in VS. I also tried passing in null, 11111111, (for binary) even looked at other stored procedures which store images, they dont have an image data type the use a max binary.

I dont need to ever use the column again I only need it populated in order to create a record.
How can I enter in dummy data which the data type image will accent?
Please adivse

ALso tried creating a var image = new image and passing that in but it was passing in the control.
So populated it and passed it to the SP. stil not joy

Comment: Why use IMAGE when you can probably use VARBINARY(MAX)?

Comment: because the asp.net stored procedure expects image type

Comment: @John what you mean with 'this does not work in VS'? the record is not created, i suppose, but anithing else happens? any error message?